# How to send [:commit] param with remote: true form_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form and I need to have 2 submit buttons.  This seems like the only way I can think to do to accomplish what I want.

The goal is to use one form to send to one method and then possibly redirect to another method depending on the params passed because the functions will be different.

Form:

```
<%= form_for(:mass, url: mass_product_variant_category_path, method: :get, remote: true) do |mass| %>
    <%= mass.submit "Update All", name: "All", class: "btn btn-light" %>
    <%= mass.submit "Update Files", name: "Files", class: "btn btn-light" %>
    <% @Stuff.each do |variant| %>
       <%= check_box_tag 'store_variant_ids[]', variant.id %>
    <% end %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I tried: `<%= submit_tag "Submit", name: "All" %>`, also not working.

The html:

`<input type="submit" name="File" value="Update Files" class="btn btn-light" data-disable-with="Update Files">`

Controller:

```
def mass_product_variant_category
   @stuff = Stuff.where(store_variant_id: params[:store_variant_ids])
   if params[:commit] == "File"
     redirect_to edit_multiple_stuffs_path(stuffs: @stuffs)
   else
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js
     end
   end
end
```

The params that get passed are:

`{..."mass" => {hidden_field: "int"}, "other_attributes" => ["int"]...}`

This is due to using `remote: true`, but not sure why or how.

How can I pass through a param based on the submit form?

I've read other SO posts on this, but there are very few and none seem to have a good or any accepted answers.  I also cannot use hidden_fields due to needing a redirect based on submit button used.

Is there a "Rails" way to do this without needing to add javascript or is that my only option?

Comment: I am not sure about multiple submits but why don't you add a field with two radio buttons called "Update All" and "Update Files" (one selected by default) and then add only one submit button. Radio buttons set the `commit` param to "All" or "Files" based on selection and you get the functionality you want. Will it help? If it will work for you but you are confused about how, I will add an answer with code for the form.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I ended up setting a hidden field tag which takes a param based on the submit button through an onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a `hidden_field_tag` within the form that gets filled in based on the submit button used through an onclick.  I can then check the hidden_fields param in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The "name" attribute maps to the name in the `params` hash. For this case you should do something like:

```
if params["File"]
  # Something
elsif params["All"]
  # Other thing
else
  # Default
end
```